# How do I use SQL to populate a column in APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

as the question states, I want to fill a column of a master page table (in master detail form) with value that I need to get from an SQL query. Let's say I have two relations where the first has attributes `name` (PK) and category and the second has `account_name` (PK) and `name` (FK for first relation).

My master table should display first relation + special column that will show the number of account_names per name. What I've done so far is: I've added a new column and specified its type as `SQL Expression`, and under the SQL Expression I've written

```
    SELECT COUNT(ACCOUNT_NAME)
    FROM ACCOUNTS
    WHERE NAME = :NAME;
```

where `ACCOUNTS` is the 2nd relation. My solution obviously doesn't work and for the last 2 hours of googling I couldn't find appropriate explanation whether it be official or unofficial.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any special APEX features, just write an SQL query with an aggregate:

```
select m.name, m.category, count(a.account_name)
  from master_table m left join accounts a on a.name = m.name
 group by m.name, m.category
```

That's enough.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what those "relation" you mentioned mean.

Anyway: I tried it on master-detail Scott's tables (DEPT being master, EMP detail), letting wizard to create a default form.

Then I created a new column for the DEPT region (right-click "Columns" under the DEPT region, "Create column"). I named it CNT_EMP (i.e. it is supposed to show how many employees work in every department).

Navigate to CNT_EMP's "Source" section; type is "SQL Expression" (just like you did it). If you look at Help for it, you'll see that it allows such a command:

```
(select count(*) from emp e where e.deptno = deptno)
```

Well, it won't work. First of all, Apex raises a warning saying "ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: ORA-00936: missing expression" but you can ignore it (*any* expression you enter raises some error, as far as I can tell. As if it is a bug), run the page - you'll get 14 employees for every department (which is wrong).

That's why I created a (stored) function:

```
create or replace function f_emp_per_dept (par_deptno in number)
  return number
is
  retval number;
begin
  select count(*) into retval
  from emp
  where deptno = par_deptno;

  return (retval);
end;
```

and used it in the CNT_EMP's SQL Expression, as

```
f_emp_per_dept(deptno)
```

(Error again, ignore it, save page, run it). Guess what? It works as expected, counts employees per departments!

Therefore, I'd suggest you do the same - create a function and call it from item's SQL Expression.

On the other hand, what @Dmitry has said stands - why would you want to do it this way, when there's a far simpler solution (have a look at his example)?